# Why is this forEach function repeating last value in all elements?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Look at this code:

```js
var machines = [{
  "name": "inclinedPlane",
  "images": {
    "draggable": {
      "src": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/mc_inclinedPlane.png",
      "sound": "@@instanceAssets/assets/audios/inclinedPlane.mp3"
    },
    "drop": {
      "default": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/inclinedPlaneSong.png",
      "onDrop": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/inclinedPlaneSongFilled.png"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "pulley",
  "images": {
    "draggable": {
      "src": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/mc_pulley.png",
      "sound": "@@instanceAssets/assets/audios/pulley.mp3"
    },
    "drop": {
      "default": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/pulleySong.png",
      "onDrop": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/pulleySongFilled.png"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "lever",
  "images": {
    "draggable": {
      "src": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/mc_lever.png",
      "sound": "@@instanceAssets/assets/audios/lever.mp3"
    },
    "drop": {
      "default": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/leverSong.png",
      "onDrop": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/leverSongFilled.png"
    }
  }
}];

var drops = {
  "component": "DropContainer",
  "parent": "main",
  "style": {
    "type": "image",
    "scale": { "x": 1, "y": 1 }
  }
};
```

I want to assign the the `default` value of each machine `drop` image to the `src` attribute of the merged object's `style`.

```
machines.forEach((machine) => {
    const config = Object.assign(machine.images.drop, drops);
    config.style.src = machine.images.drop.default;
    console.log(config);
});
```

But for some reason, the`src` value on each object's `style` is always being the last one for all objects. I can't see why is this happening and I've spent a lot of time on this with no results. Can you see what's going on here?

Comment: if by the vague "that value" you mean the value that is output using `console.log` ... then .. you are wrong ... the output is different for each `machine`

Comment: Oh, you mean that each `config.style.src` is the same?

Comment: Yeah, it's always being the value of the last object in the array.

Comment: I do not see that code in the fiddle....

Comment: looks like you are just reassigning the value of config.style.src on each iteration of the forEach loop

Comment: changes to `config.style` are also changes to `drops.style` - because they are the same object

Comment: Yeah, but how can I achieve what I want? I tried merging the style object instead and the same thing is happening.

Comment: you will want to use an array or a map to return an array of objects

Comment: I can give you an example in a minute and you can let me know if it works for.

Comment: One (I think nasty looking, but works) way - `const config = Object.assign(machine.images.drop, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(drops)));`

Comment: @JaromandaX that was nasty hehehe :-)

Answer (score 1):

- You need to put the drops object inside of function `forEach`.

  > The problem you're facing is the reference of the same object `drops` in every assign you're executing.
- Set the default value as follow: `config.style.src = machine.images.drop.default;`

```js
var machines = [{    "name": "inclinedPlane",    "images": {      "draggable": {        "src": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/mc_inclinedPlane.png",        "sound": "@@instanceAssets/assets/audios/inclinedPlane.mp3"      },      "drop": {        "default": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/inclinedPlaneSong.png",        "onDrop": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/inclinedPlaneSongFilled.png"      }    }  },  {    "name": "pulley",    "images": {      "draggable": {        "src": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/mc_pulley.png",        "sound": "@@instanceAssets/assets/audios/pulley.mp3"      },      "drop": {        "default": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/pulleySong.png",        "onDrop": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/pulleySongFilled.png"      }    }  },  {    "name": "lever",    "images": {      "draggable": {        "src": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/mc_lever.png",        "sound": "@@instanceAssets/assets/audios/lever.mp3"      },      "drop": {        "default": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/leverSong.png",        "onDrop": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/leverSongFilled.png"      }    }  }];

machines.forEach((machine) => {
  var drops = {    "component": "DropContainer",    "parent": "main",    "style": {      "type": "image",      "scale": {        "x": 1,        "y": 1      }    }  };
  
  const config = Object.assign(machine.images.drop, drops);
  config.style.src = machine.images.drop.default;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(machines, null, 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output after this simple change:

You already have the default property on the config object (in the root). You obtained it when you created your "merged" object.  So...

**Change**

```
config.style.src = machine.images.drop;
```

**To**

```
config.style.src = config.default;
```

And that produces this output:

```
config.style.src: @@instanceAssets/assets/images/inclinedPlaneSong.png
config.style.src: @@instanceAssets/assets/images/pulleySong.png
config.style.src: @@instanceAssets/assets/images/leverSong.png
```

========================================

```js
var machines = [{
  "name": "inclinedPlane",
  "images": {
    "draggable": {
      "src": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/mc_inclinedPlane.png",
      "sound": "@@instanceAssets/assets/audios/inclinedPlane.mp3"
    },
    "drop": {
      "default": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/inclinedPlaneSong.png",
      "onDrop": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/inclinedPlaneSongFilled.png"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "pulley",
  "images": {
    "draggable": {
      "src": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/mc_pulley.png",
      "sound": "@@instanceAssets/assets/audios/pulley.mp3"
    },
    "drop": {
      "default": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/pulleySong.png",
      "onDrop": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/pulleySongFilled.png"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "lever",
  "images": {
    "draggable": {
      "src": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/mc_lever.png",
      "sound": "@@instanceAssets/assets/audios/lever.mp3"
    },
    "drop": {
      "default": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/leverSong.png",
      "onDrop": "@@instanceAssets/assets/images/leverSongFilled.png"
    }
  }
}];

var drops = {
  "component": "DropContainer",
  "parent": "main",
  "style": {
    "type": "image",
    "scale": { "x": 1, "y": 1 }
  }
};

machines.forEach((machine) => {
    const config = Object.assign(machine.images.drop, drops);
    config.style.src = config.default;
    console.log('config.style.src: ' + config.style.src);
});
```

Comment: No, I made an error. That's how the code should be, and it still happens what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I'm running your snippet and the problem still persists. All `style.src` values are the same

Comment: I have no idea how that's possible. I have printed the output in my answer for you to see. In that printout each `style.src` property is absolutely different!

Comment: I've simplified this to show you the output for each `.src` and that they are different.